# Dash/Plotly chart doesn't show when run from Raspberry PI

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, plotly-dash, werkzeug

I am trying to chart real time data from a Raspberry Pi to a web server. In this case I am using dash (https://dash.plot.ly/live-updates) to do this. I am currently testing my dash web browser on static data on my mac, and so far it works just fine. Aside from a deprecation message about plotly, and a No Handlers could be found for logger "werkzeug", it works completely fine. BUT when I try to run the exact same script on my raspberry Pi, I hit problems.

On my raspberry Pi, the web server runs, I can open it up on localhost, but the charts are empty!!! I get no error messages or reasons why this is happening!

[image: What pops up on the Pi]

[image: What pops up on my Mac]

EDIT: Script added

```
import os, sys
from pathlib import Path
currDir = Path(os.path.abspath(__file__))
_rootDir = currDir.parent.parent
# _dataDir = str(_rootDir / 'GridBallast-RaspberryPI' / 'data')
_dataDir = str(_rootDir / 'data')


import ETL
import datetime
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        html.H4('RaspberryPI Sensor Charts'),
        html.Div(id='live-update-text'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph'),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=1*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        )
    ])
)


@app.callback(Output('live-update-text', 'children'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
def update_metrics(n):
    Temperature, Time = ETL.extractLastTemp(os.path.join(_dataDir, 'tempData.csv'))
    style = {'padding': '2px', 'fontSize': '16px'}
    return [
        html.Span('Temperature: {}'.format(Temperature), style=style),
        html.Span('Time: {}'.format(Time), style=style)
    ]


@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])

def update_graph_live(n):

    #Load Temp Data 
    tempDict = ETL.etlTransform(os.path.join(_dataDir, 'tempData.csv'))
    lightDict = ETL.etlTransform(os.path.join(_dataDir, 'lightData.csv'))
    currentDict = ETL.etlTransform(os.path.join(_dataDir, 'currentData.csv'))
    # Create the graph with subplots
    fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.2, subplot_titles=("Temperature", "Light", "Current"))
    fig['layout']['margin'] = {
        'l': 30, 'r': 10, 'b': 30, 't': 25
    }
    fig['layout']['legend'] = {'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'xanchor': 'left'}
    fig['layout']['height'] = 900

    fig.append_trace({
        'x': tempDict.keys(),
        'y': tempDict.values(),
        'name': 'Temp vs. Time',
        'mode': 'lines+markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 1, 1)
    fig.append_trace({
        'x': lightDict.keys(),
        'y': lightDict.values(),
        # 'text': data['time'],
        'name': 'Light vs. Time',
        'mode': 'markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 2, 1)
    fig.append_trace({
        'x': currentDict.keys(),
        'y': currentDict.values(),
        # 'text': data['time'],
        'name': 'Current vs. Time',
        'mode': 'markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 3, 1)

    return fig


def main():
    app.run_server(debug = True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(_dataDir)
    print(os.listdir(_dataDir))
    main()
    # app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you post your plotly code? Also, your pi has the same static data and file structure as your mac, right?

Comment: Yes the file structure is the same. I know this because I print an os.listdir(_dataDir) and it returns the expected results i.e. a list of data files in the _dataDir directory.

Comment: Does your `pi` have internet access? Can you `print(tempDict, lightDict, currentDict)` after making it in your `update_graph_live` function to make sure it has the data?

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve], i.e. something everyone can just grab and run to see your problem. Also, how is it relevant that this runs on a raspberry-pi or where the data comes from? Lastly, please read the description of tags before applying them, e.g. the use of the "linux" tag shows you didn't.

Comment: @MasonCaiby Yes printing the dictionaries work fine in the update_graph_live function. But the graph online remains unchanged. I also thought maybe the data files contained too many entries, so I made them only contain a few entries. None of these solutions work. I will also add that the tab is continuously 'updating....' where as on the mac, the tab alternates between reading 'Dash' and then 'Updating.....'. IT appears that the RPI version never seems to update in the browser.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt
Certainly, below is a Dash tutorial which similarly fails on the Raspberry Pi. 
1. Assemble Raspberry Pi 3 and connect to internet
2. Install Dash as so from https://dash.plot.ly/installation
3. Copy code from tutorial from, https://dash.plot.ly/live-updates
4. Watch how the live-updates never occur, all that is displayed is an empty graph

Comment: @MasonCaiby I tried to reproduce the issue with a Dash-live-updates tutorial, and it fails in a similar manner. Maybe this is an issue with dash or chromium. 

tutorial being used found here: https://dash.plot.ly/live-updates

Comment: Sorry, misunderstanding: It is your task to extract a [mcve], which implies stripping out anything that's not necessary to reproduce the problem, even if that is fundamental for the original task. Then, you post that information inline (not via links!) in the question.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for the guidance, next time I'll be sure to try and reduce the problem. Part of the issue here was that I was so lost I had no idea on how to reduce it. But I was able to fix my issue, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

so I was able to fix the issue by increasing the update interval. I guess on raspberry Pi, the interval needs to be larger in order for the chart to update correctly. Weird, but it works.